# Find connected components with OpenCV based on existed labeling, but not binary image

Tags: c++, opencv

OpenCV has a function to find connected components on a binary image:([cv::connectedComponents()](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a)), but it doesn't account for existed labels. What is the proper way to find connected components only within pixels with the same labels?

For example, I have the code:

```
Mat test = Mat::zeros(1, 4, DataType<int>::type);
test.at<int>(0, 0) = 1;
test.at<int>(0, 1) = 2;
test.at<int>(0, 2) = 0;
test.at<int>(0, 3) = 1;
test.convertTo(test, CV_8U);
connectedComponents(test, test);

std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

It has input matrix `[1, 2, 0, 1]`, and labels it as `[1, 1, 0, 2]`. But I want to get `[1, 2, 0, 3]`. Is there a way to do it with OpenCV?

Comment: Why the last 1 becomes a 3? Why the first 1 should remain unchanged? What's the difference between the first and the last 1 in the input matrix?

Comment: Because 0-label means background, and there is no way from the first 1 to the last 1, which wouldn't include the background.

Comment: so [3, 2, 0, 1] as a result would be equally valid?

Comment: Yes, as well as [3, 1, 0, 2].

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the problem:

```
Mat connected_components(const Mat &labels)
{
    Mat res, input;
    labels.convertTo(input, CV_8U);

    connectedComponents(input, res);
    res.convertTo(res, DataType<int>::type);

    double n_labels;
    minMaxLoc(res, nullptr, &n_labels);

    res += labels * (n_labels + 1);

    std::map<int, int> new_ids;
    for (int row = 0; row < labels.rows; ++row)
    {
        auto row_res_data = res.ptr<int>(row);
        for (int col = 0; col < labels.cols; ++col)
        {
            auto cur_lab = row_res_data[col];
            if (cur_lab == 0)
                continue;

            auto iter = new_ids.emplace(cur_lab, new_ids.size() + 1);
            row_res_data[col] = iter.first->second;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```